# Getting reference of dereferenced element from container of pointers by ranged loop

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, auto, ranged-loops

Given a container of pointers to `int`s, how can I increment the `int`s without using a dereference operator `*` within the loop body `{}`?

Here's the implementation with the dereference operator in the loop body:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 0, y = 1, z = 2;

    auto increment_elements = [](vector<int*>& v) {
        for (auto& i : v) { ++*i };
    };

    increment_elements(vector<int*>{&x, &y, &z});

    cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << endl;
}
```

Replacing

```
for (auto& i : v) { ++*i };
```

with

```
for (int& i : v) { ++i };
```

gives MSVC-2013

`error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int &'`.

Why does replacement with

```
for (auto& i : v) { ++i };
```

compile but without incrementing the `int`s, and what is it doing?

I have the same question regarding replacement with

```
for (int*& i : v) ++i;
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: `++i` increments the pointer itself. Why don't you want to use the dereference operator?

Comment: `auto` deduces the element type as `int*` so `decltype(i)` becomes `int*&` which does the same as your last example. Applying the plus operator to a pointer incremenets the pointer but not what it points to.

Comment: You iterate over a container of *pointers*. Each element is a pointer - of course you need to dereference it to access the object it points to. What do you feel is wrong with using `*`?

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer to get to the element. There's no avoiding it.

Comment: Or pass an `Object { x, y, z }` by reference, so the `*` dereference operator will be hidden.

Comment: @mr5 , Do you mean to use a custom `Object` to wrap the vector of pointers? Or do you mean to replace the `vector<int*>` with `vector<int>`? The `vector<int*>` is an irremovable item in my OP.  @T.C., @Igor Tandetnik, I'm just trying to learn the rules and alternatives. There's nothing wrong with `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a container of pointers to ints, how can I increment the ints without using a dereference operator `*` within the loop body `{}`?

Uses references over pointers whenever you can. You can't make vector of reference type so instead you can use a `std::reference_wrapper<int>`.

```c++
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v{x, y, z};
```

`increment_elements` should probably also take a range to stay in line with generic programming. Then use `get()` on the elements and increment them:

```c++
template<class Iter>
void increment_elements(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first->get(), ++first);
}
```

Then you can call it using `begin()` and `end()`:

```c++
increment_elements(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

Or if you still want to take a vector as an argument, you can just iterate through and increment:

```c++
for (int& i : v) ++i;
```

and call it as:

```c++
increment_elements(v);
```

> Why does replacement with [...] compile but without incrementing the ints, and what is it doing?

`auto` deduces the element type as `int*` so `decltype(i)` becomes `int*&` which does the same thing as your last example.

Comment: You read my mind. Reference-like usage was exactly what I wanted. Your generic programming example adds a comprehensive touch.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector is `vector<int *>`, **not `vector<int>`!**

```
vector<int *> &v;
for (auto &i : v)
    ++(*i);
```

`v` is vector of `int *`. so, the type of `i` is `int* &`. Therefore, you should use `++(*i);` to increase `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
for (int &i : v)
    ++i;
```

This is wrong. `v` is vector of `int *`, but you're trying to assign `int *` to `int &`.

```
for (auto &i : v)
    ++i;
```

This code is increase *the pointers*, not `x`, `y`, `z`. Since it's equal to

```
for (std::vector<int *>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    ++(*it);
```